# Save 10 lines from Help into txt file

Tags: command-line

I need to save first 10 lines from manual for command `man` to txt file.

First step I have command `man man` but what to do next?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Isn’t this a homework question? Exactly 10 lines of `man man` look quite useless…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipes and head will do what you need:

```
man man | head -10 > file.txt
```

`head -n` where `n` = number of lines you want

Comment: Moreover 10 lines are default, so you can leave out the parameter `-10` completely.

Comment: Since @SteamerJ posted the right answer before, I'll delete my answer (because they are the same) and upvote his answer.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you.
Good to know about 10 lines being the default.
@singrium, I saw that right after I posted, I had a message. Keep up the vigilant knowledge sharing!